# How should I join below queries so that I can put them in 1 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please suggest how should I join below SQL queries.

```
Select Name AVG(datediff(dd, cast(App as Date), cast(Fund as Date)))    
from Main    
where Folder in ('Employee Crew', 'Crew')     
  and Month(Fund) = Month(getdate()) AND Year(Fund) = Year(getdate())    
Group By Crew


select Name AVG(datediff(dd, cast(App as Date), cast(Fund as Date)))        
from Main
where Folder in ('Employee Crew', 'Crew')
  and datediff(dd,cast(Fund as date),cast(getdate()as date)) between 0 and 90
Group By Crew


select Name AVG(datediff(dd, cast(App as Date), cast(Fund as Date)))
from Main     
where Folder in ('Employee Crew', 'Crew')     
  and datediff(dd,cast(Fund as date),cast(getdate()as date)) between 0 and 360        
Group By Crew
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server I am using.

Comment: No JOIN needed. Use `case` _expressions_ to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Tried case but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Select    
case when Month(Funding_Date) = Month(getdate()) AND    Year(Funding_Date)     = Year(getdate()) and  datediff(dd, cast(Application_Taken_Date as Date),     cast(GETDATE() as Date)) between 0 and 31 then     'CurrentMonthAVg' else null END as 'CurrentMonthAVg'     
from Encompass_Main A

Comment: You `GROUP BY crew` and `SELECT name`?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would really help here. Judging by the discrepancies between the column names in your question vs. your comment above, and the problem @forpas noted with your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, I'm guessing that you simplified the original query somewhat for the question and made some mistakes along the way, which makes it hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm surprised if your query run.

Comment: My all 3 queries run seperately ang gives output as

Comment: 1. Name, (Current Month Avg)    2. Name, (Past 90 Days Avg)     3. Name, 'Past 1 year Avg'

Comment: May I give you some suggestions: 1. Don't comment under every answer that code is 'not working' - that's not specifying what the problem is, be more specific please. 2. Correct your query: if Name is a column, then a comma is missing. But there will be a logical issue becuase if you run that you will get 'Name is not valid in the SELECT list because it is not in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'-like error, right? 3. Please add to the question if you want 3 different columns for the 3 averages, or you want 1 average column and the results from the 3 queries would merge vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION between two queries

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Comment: Or UNION ALL if you do not want a `distinct` operation to happen. [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: UNION is not getting desired result. Union all is not working :( .

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select Name, Crew,
       avg(case when Month(Fund) = Month(getdate()) AND Year(Fund) = Year(getdate()) 
                then datediff(day, cast(App as Date), cast(Fund as Date))
           end),
       avg(case when datediff(day, cast(Fund as date), cast(getdate() as date)) between 0 and 90 
                then datediff(day, cast(App as Date), cast(Fund as Date))
           end),
       avg(case when datediff(day, cast(Fund as date), cast(getdate() as date)) between 0 and 360  
                then datediff(day, cast(App as Date), cast(Fund as Date))
           end)
from Main     
where Folder in ('Employee Crew', 'Crew')       
Group By Name, Crew
```

Comment: maybe they were disturbed by the fact that you have the attribute `name` behind the `SELECT` that is not behind `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @RadimBača . . . That is in the OP's queries.  I didn't even look at whether they match.  In any case, an anonymous downvote doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, your idea seems great, but I am not able to run this query, it says incorrect syntax ')' in Line 4. And I am not able to resolve it.

Comment: @Shenk . . . Oops, the `case` expressions required `end`s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree

Comment: Can you please edit your query @GordonLinoff because I tried and it is not working at my end. Thanks!

Comment: Can anybody show me how can I use temporary tables here, so I can store result of all three query in temporary tables and pull from there in the main query.@GordonLinoff or anyone who is willing to help. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Shenk - Gordon's answer is about the best guess possible with the information you've given us. You haven't said what your table looks like, what data it contains, what results you expect, or exactly what about the query isn't working. If you want another answer, update your question with details. Otherwise, we're just taking shots in the dark.